# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined after activating site with wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, styles, typeerror

so when testing the site and when the site is "coming soon mode" no errors are thrown. When I activated the site I get this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

it doesnt like the line:
`slides[num].style.opacity = "1";`

the whole function is:

```
function fade(num){
  var i;
  var slides = document.querySelector("#currentEvent").childNodes;
  var dots = document.querySelector(".dots");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.opacity = "0";  
  }
  
   for (i = 0; i < dots.childNodes.length; i++) {
      dots.childNodes[i].className = dots.childNodes[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  slides[num].style.opacity = "1";  
  dots.childNodes[num].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. It's hard to say with this context, a link to the site might be helpful, but it looks like it isn't finding the slides variable and/or the slides variable is not an array. I would start with console logging slides after you assign it and see what shows up.

Comment: https://tahsiscommunity.com/ this is the site. this is supposed to control the event banner

Comment: Your #currentEvent div is empty on the site, so slides is an empty array and therefore slides[num] will return undefined.